# Ms Access: Why isn't the textbox on my form displaying the results of a query?

Tags: forms, ms-access-2010

I want to do something rather fancy with my form. Based on the input of 2 other textboxes, I want to have a textbox (or some form of displaying info) show the query results of using the other 2 pieces of information. Is this possible?? The resulting textbox would be read-only. I only need to show them.

Answer (score 0):

[Try this post](http://www.access-programmers.co.uk/forums/showthread.php?t=188663). I integrated this in my database and customized it according to our needs. It worked wonders.